# Add all timezones from pytz to a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add all the timezones to a tuple in Python. I have done it this way:

```
ALL_TIMEZONES = (
    for idx, tz in enumerate(pytz.all_timezones):
        (idx, (tz)),
)
```

But I get a syntax error when `for` starts.

Why can't I do it that way? Must I do the iteration *outside* the tuple and append?

Comment: I suggest you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/comprehensions

Comment: Your instinct is correct, you cannot put a for loop, *in that form*, inside a tuple.

Comment: ```Why can't I do it that way? ``` - because the language does not allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it that way because your expression is not producing a value.

You can use a generator expression to achieve that:

```
ALL_TIMEZONES = tuple((idx, tz) for idx, tz in enumerate(pytz.all_timezones))
```

Comment: I believe you have created a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression), not a list comprehension.

Comment: True, since it's using a tuple. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm,,, it is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) because ```"...it is enclosed in parentheses instead of brackets or curly braces."```

Answer (score 1):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns an iterator which produces tuples when you iterate over it.  [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple) will consume an iterator. So ...

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> tuple(enumerate(a))
((0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'))
>>>
```

For your solution:

```
tuple(enumerate(pytz.all_timezones))
```